# how to create a rank system

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user table with `user_score` column in view side I want to show every user rank and score and 2 people before/after him.

how can I implement this with MySQL or PHP with minimum execution time?

**example**

```
+-----------+------------+
| User_id   | Score      |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 12258      |
| 2         | 112        |
| 3         | 9678       |
| 4         | 689206     |
| 5         | 1868       |
+-----------+------------+
```

for example my `user_id = 3`. I want to show like this

```
                    you
                   9678    

 user befor you               user after you
    12258                            1868
```

Comment: Cool, Write some `php` code to achieve that.

Comment: This should be handled in your PHP presentation layer rather than in MySQL.

Comment: I doubt this is possible in a single go (query). You will need to take a two step approach.

Comment: not an easy task, some php and sql wizardry requried. Google `leaderboard design sql`, you find a host of (partial|potential) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only MySQL:

SELECT usr.`user_id`, (SELECT usr1.`user_score` FROM `user` usr1 WHERE usr.`user_score` >= usr1.`user_score` AND usr.`user_id` != usr1.`user_id` ORDER BY usr1.`user_score` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `user_before_you`, usr.`user_score` AS `you`, (SELECT usr1.`user_score` FROM `user` usr1 WHERE usr.`user_score` <= usr1.`user_score` AND usr.`user_id` != usr1.`user_id` ORDER BY usr1.`user_score` ASC LIMIT 1) AS `user_after_you` FROM `user` usr WHERE 1

Comment: Thanks very much, its working perfectly but this code have problem that didn't return ID of users before and after current user and may we have conflict